# Strange neural network output

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am programming in MATLAB and I am trying to use the Neural Network Toolbox but I have troubles in calculating the output of a network. I will try to explain my problem: I have defined a very simple ANN with one hidden layer and linear activation functions. So if I have an input x, then I expect the output of the hidden layer to be

```
 h = w * x + b
```

where w are the weights and b the biases. Then I expect my output to be

```
o = w' * h + b'
```

where w' are the weights between the hidden layer and the output and b' the biases.

Now the problem is that if I do

```
o = net(x)
```

this doesn't happen. Here is my code:

```
  net = feedforwardnet([layer1], 'traincgp');

  net = configure(net, Dtrain, Dtrain);

  net.trainParam.epochs = 0;

  net.IW{1,1} = weights12;
  net.LW{2,1} = my_weights;
  net.b{1} = bias12;

  for ii=1:size(net.layers, 1)
      net.layers{ii}.transferFcn = 'purelin';
  end;
  net = train(net, Dtrain, Dtrain);
```

As you can see I am training for 0 epochs since this is just a test and I am also using Dtrain both as input and target since I am training an autoencoder. As I said, the problem is that if I calculate the output as I wrote before I get one result, while if I do

```
output = net(input)
```

I get another one. What should I do to have the same result?

Comment: For some reason, the person that edited your question saw fit to delete a line of your code as well. Please check the edits that were made to make sure they are correct, and roll them back if they are not.

Comment: @skrrgwasme thank you: now the code is fixed

Comment: @SteveFerg Please be more careful when you edit questions. Your previous edit on this question removed a line of code.

Comment: My humble apologies! Thank-you for catching it.

Comment: @skrrgwasme: I added that line of code in an edit, so maybe SteveFerg edit the still-not-edited-version of the question. Anyway, problem solved.